# Dynamic Linq Expression Query Nested List Object

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

Is it possible to dynamically build an IQueryable/Linq Expression with filtering criteria based on a NESTED/Child List Object's Property.

I have not included all code here - particularly the code around Pagination but I hope there is sufficient detail. Things to note is my use of EFCore5 and Automapper ProjectTo extension method.

For Example:

```
    public class PersonModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public PersonName Name { get; set; }
        public List<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
    }

    [Owned]
    public class PersonName
    {
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string GivenNames { get; set; }
    }


    public class Pet
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string TypeOfAnimal { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my WebApi Controller.

```
     [HttpGet(Name = nameof(GetAllPersons))]
     public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<PersonDTO>>> GetAllPersons(
            [FromQuery] QueryStringParameters parameters)
        {
            IQueryable<Person> persons = _context.Persons;

            parameters.FilterClauses.ForEach(filter =>
                persons = persons.Where(filter.name, filter.op, filter.val));
            // Note the use of 'Where' Extension Method.

            var dTOs = persons
                .ProjectTo<PersonDTO>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);;

            var pagedPersons = PaginatedList<PersonDTO>
                .CreateAsync(dTOs, parameters);

            return Ok(await pagedPersons);

        }
```

To query for all people with a Name.GivenNames property equal to "John" I would issue a GET call such as;

```
http://127.0.0.1/api/v1.0/?Filter=Name.GivenNames,==,John
```

This works perfectly fine.

However I would like to query for all people with a Pet with a Name property equal to "Scruffy" I would issue a GET call such as;

```
http://127.0.0.1/api/v1.0/?Filter=Pets.Name,==,Scruffy
```

Somewhat expectedly it throws the following exception on the line of code in BuildPredicate Function. This is because "Pets" is Type is a "List"... not a "Pet"

```
 var left = propertyName.Split... 

 Instance property 'Pet:Name' is not defined for type 
 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Person]' (Parameter 'propertyName')
```

Here are the Extension Methods.

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
    {

        public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyName, string comparison, string value)
        {
            return source.Where(BuildPredicate<T>(propertyName, comparison, value));
        }
    }

         public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildPredicate<T>(string propertyName, string comparison, string value)
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
            var left = propertyName.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.Property);
            var body = MakeComparison(left, comparison, value);
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
        }

        private static Expression MakeComparison(Expression left, string comparison, string value)
        {
            switch (comparison)
            {
                case "==":
                    return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, left, value);
                case "!=":
                    return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.NotEqual, left, value);
                case ">":
                    return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.GreaterThan, left, value);
                case ">=":
                    return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual, left, value);
                case "<":
                    return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.LessThan, left, value);
                case "<=":
                    return MakeBinary(ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual, left, value);
                case "Contains":
                case "StartsWith":
                case "EndsWith":
                    return Expression.Call(MakeString(left), comparison, Type.EmptyTypes, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string)));
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException($"Invalid comparison operator '{comparison}'.");
            }
        }

        private static Expression MakeString(Expression source)
        {
            return source.Type == typeof(string) ? source : Expression.Call(source, "ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);
        }

        private static Expression MakeBinary(ExpressionType type, Expression left, string value)
        {
            object typedValue = value;
            if (left.Type != typeof(string))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    typedValue = null;
                    if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(left.Type) == null)
                        left = Expression.Convert(left, typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(left.Type));
                }
                else
                {
                    var valueType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(left.Type) ?? left.Type;                  
                    typedValue = valueType.IsEnum ? Enum.Parse(valueType, value) :
                        valueType == typeof(Guid) ? Guid.Parse(value) :
                        valueType == typeof(DateTimeOffset) ? DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal) :
                        Convert.ChangeType(value, valueType);                    
                }
            }
            var right = Expression.Constant(typedValue, left.Type);
            return Expression.MakeBinary(type, left, right);
        }
```

Is there anyway to adapt this code to detect that if one of the nested properties is a LIST that it builds an 'Inner Predicate' to do a query on the child collection? ie: Enumerable.Any() ?

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with raw expression tree's, it sometimes helps to start with an example, let the C# compiler have a go at it, and work backwards. [eg](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEEAsBuWDkQHQBkBLAOwEdM4kUCTTcBRADwAcAnAUwGdPCB7YzhSwBmZGEQAFdgBcA3rESLkolEgBivXolmIA5jPSJOBxAF9Y5uCvFTWnfvJhLliAG6FW0gK4BDADaIAJIAwrx+fuwAxtJ8xAA8UtIAfJIynNp6JsbShpaWImKIwdoKSiAqqIgAsgAUAJQlTs5KTGxcPPxxIACsCex2/AA0AEaafkkp7CysiAC8iMxzKcy4iZy4AILEAJ410kuI0rgaWrPzAETDfj4AFud1FM55QA);

```cs
Expression<Func<Person,bool>> expr = p => p.Pets.Any(t => t.Foo == "blah");
```

Though the compiler does take a shortcut in IL to specify type members that can't be decompiled.

The trick here is to make your method recursive. Instead of assuming that you can get each property;

```cs
var left = propertyName.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.Property);
```

If you find a collection property in the list, you need to call `BuildPredicate<Pet>` with the remaining property string. Then use the return value as the argument to call `.Pets.Any(...)`.

Perhaps something like;

```cs
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildPredicate<T>(string propertyName, string comparison, string value)
    => (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)BuildPredicate(typeof(T), propertyName.Split('.'), comparison, value);

public static LambdaExpression BuildPredicate(Type t, Span<string> propertyNames, string comparison, string value)
{
    var parameter= Expression.Parameter(t, "x");
    var p = (Expression)parameter;
    for(var i=0; i<propertyNames.Length; i++)
    {
        var method = p.Type.GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "GetEnumerator" && m.ReturnType.IsGenericType);
        if (method != null)
        {
            BuildPredicate(method.ReturnType.GetGenericArguments()[0], propertyNames.Slice(i), comparison, value);
            // TODO ...
        }
        else
            p = Expression.Property(p, propertyNames[i]);
    }
    // TODO ...
    return Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
}
```